# Movie (maybe show?) where clinic is held hostage for adult son who dies

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

At the latest, I saw this movie in January of 2008 on TV. I'll describe what I remember and see if it rings any bells.

There were three adult men, including what I believe to be a father and a son. The adult son has been critically injured, so the two other men hold a clinic hostage. The third man in the group is volatile and even goes so far as to try and rape one of the female doctors, when the son flat-lines.

The doctor cannot save the son, but the hostages hide this by putting a heart monitor in their coat pocket.

The volatile man eventually notices this and attempts to shoot the man who put it in his pocket. The doctor shoots the volatile man, who falls to the ground, unconscious. The doctor immediately takes a scalpel, opens him up, then she slides her hand in and tries to restart his heart.

I don't remember anything beyond this. Does this ring a bell for anyone?

**EDIT #1:** To answer's Walt's questions, here's what I remember: I am pretty sure it was American, the production value was good and I watched it inside a hotel in Grangeville, Idaho. The rape scene had the man pushing the doctor's back against a shelf in the operating room, where she huffs and when the patient flatlines, she pushes her would-be rapist out of the way to try to resuscitate the man's heart, saying something like, "I don't have time for this."

**EDIT #2:** It is possible that the film involves two brothers, instead of a father and son.

Comment: Could it possibly be John Q. I have not watched the movie, but I heard that the plot has something to which dad taking clinic/hospital hostage.

Comment: How about The Clinic - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Clinic_(TV_series)#Season_7

Comment: @ChickenWing24, it is not John Q. I'll take a look at The Clinic.

Comment: Check out Season 7 Episode 8 of The Clinic. It's the final episode where something similar to what you described happened. Can't find any of the episodes online though.

Comment: Thanks. This is all vaguely familiar, esp. the 3 archetypes (though I'm picturing a wounded younger *brother*, his older caring brother and their loose cannon accomplice), but this is unfortunately a [very common plot](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CodeSilver) (esp. in medical dramas), so I just can't place it. :(

Comment: It's possible it was a brother and not a son. I turned on the TV only after the hostage situation had begun and the guy was on the table.

Comment: Could you say anything more?  Was it an old or newish movie/show (e.g. the quality of 80s/90s/2000s production differs hugely).  Any famous actors?  What did the main actor look like (skin color, hair, etc.).  Furthermore, are you sure it was rape, and not just intimidating the doctor?

Comment: I'd say the quality was 2000s. All the main characters were Caucasian and, oddly enough, they were all brunettes. The doctor was at least beginning to get assaulted when the wounded gang member flat-lined, as the one going after her wasn't holding a gun to her head. This was an ongoing hostage situation, so there were a bunch of cops behind squad cars outside at night. I believe they entered the hospital simultaneous with the vicious one getting shot.

Comment: @DarthBotto Who were the leads? The doctors, the bad guys or the cops/negotiator outside?

Comment: @madmada It seemed as though it was the cops inside and outside. Though, the doctor who is sexually assaulted seemed to have some weight to the show, as well. But definitely about the cops' perspective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an episode from **[Chicago Hope](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108724/?ref_=tt_ov_inf)** but it's a **grocery store** instead of *clinic*.

The episode is **[The Day of the Rope](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0540309/)**

> White supremacists on the run following a failed assasination attempt against the President, hole up in a grocery store with an injured member, and demand a doctor from Chicago Hope to treat him.

First aired: 1/20/97

Comment: 15 hours until I can award you. Yes, you did it! The dialogue was pretty similar, but I must have mistook the rebel threatening the woman for rape. Perhaps it was because I was a teenager and misconstrued the sexual overtones?

Answer (score 1):

I think it pretty much sounds The clinic S07E08. You can read summary of this episode [here](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1549475/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl).

Comment: There are several similarities. However, that episode aired in November of 2009, while I saw the episode in January of 2008.

Comment: @DarthBotto what are the dissimilarities?